# Creating objects and adding them to a list by Reading CSV input in python

Tags: python, list, csv

This is currently my code for reading through a CSV file, Creating a person object, and adding each person to a list. One line Example input: **John,Langley,1,2,2,3,5**

When i print(per) each time after creating a person object. My output is correct, but as soon as i add that person to the list i made, the numeric values AKA 'traits' for that person are all the same as the last persons traits in the CSV file.

For Example:

**John,Langley,1,2,2,3,5 --(add to list)-->John,Langley,1,1,1,1,1**

**Isabel,Smith,3,2,4,4,0 --(add to list)-->Isabel,Smith,1,1,1,1,1**

**John,Doe,1,1,1,1,1 --(add to list)-->John,Doe,1,1,1,1,1**

This is impacting me with continuing because i need the person objects' traits to be valid in order to perform analysis on them in the next couple methods. PLEASE IGNORE MY PRINT STATEMENTS. THEY WERE FOR MY DEBUGGING PURPOSES

```
def read_file(filename):
    file = open(filename, "r", encoding='utf-8-sig')
    Traits_dict = {}
    pl = []
    next(file)
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        line = line.split(',')
        first = str(line[0].strip())
        last = str(line[1].strip())
        w = line[2].strip()
        hobby = line[3].strip()
        social = line[4].strip()
        eat = line[5].strip()
        sleep = line[6].strip()
        Traits_dict["Work"] = w
        Traits_dict["Hobbies"] = hobby
        Traits_dict["Socialize"] = social
        Traits_dict["Eat"] = eat
        Traits_dict["Sleep"] = sleep
        per = Person(first, last, Traits_dict)
        print(per)
        pl.append(per)
    print(pl[0])
    print(pl[1])
    print(pl[2])
    print(pl[3])
    print(pl[4])
    return pl
```

Comment: Why not use pandas dataframe?
`df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', names=['first', 'last','work','hobbies','socialize','eat','sleep'])`

Comment: I have used pandas in the past and if i could use it here i would, but i am doing a school assignment where im limited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the `Traits_dict = {}` are the same to all object since you initiating the dict before the loop so it's giving each Person object the same dict reference in it.
You can put the `Traits_dict = {}` inside the loop that it will create each Person a new dict

```
for line in file:
    Traits_dict = {}
```